# GPS to calculate distance between two points on windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gps, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

i am using GPS to calculate distance between two points i.e. i am using windows phone as a tape measure but when i start i dont get the correct value infact even if i am standing still it gives me hundreds of meter

here is my code

```
      myWatcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(myWatcher_StatusChanged);
        myWatcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(myWatcher_PositionChanged);
        myWatcher.MovementThreshold = 1;   

void myWatcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        double tempf = e.Position.Location.Latitude;
        double temps = e.Position.Location.Longitude;
        if (count2 == 0)
        {
            FirstLocation = new GeoCoordinate(tempf, temps);
            count2++;
        }
        else
        {
             double distanceInMeter;
            GeoCoordinate currentLocation;
                currentLocation = new GeoCoordinate(tempf, temps);
                distanceInMeter = currentLocation.GetDistanceTo(FirstLocation);                   

                if (App.flag == 0)
                {
                    textBlock1.Text = distanceInMeter.ToString() + " m";
                    double distanceInCm = distanceInMeter * 100;
                    textBlock2.Text = distanceInCm .ToString() + " cm";
                }
                else if (App.flag == 1)
                {
                    double distanceInInch = distanceInMeter * 39.3701;
                    textBlock1.Text = distanceInInch.ToString() + " in";
                    double distanceInFoot = distanceInMeter * 3.28084;
                    textBlock2.Text = distanceInFoot.ToString() + " ft";
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: as a tape measure?  gps is only accurate to around 8 meters in the *best case*.  if you are getting tower assisted gps instead of true gps, 100's of meters is probably best case.

Comment: so far accuracy is not an issue. i run this app and the reading at current location changes continuously while i have set movementthreshold to 1 means 1 meter of distance needs to be covered to call PositionChanged event but reading keeps on changing even though i am still

Comment: how can you say "accuracy is not an issue" if your entire question is about accuracy?  if any individual measurement of GPS is only good to within (at best!) 3 meters, any 2 measurements from the *exact same place* could be (at best!) 6 meters apart! again, **at best**.  gps is best for measuring distances on the *planet*, not on a *piece of paper*.

Comment: no thats not what i meant its just that reight now i have not reached to accurate measurement phase and i know 3 - 4 meters is accuracy and i'll make the app for that but the current issue is that even if i am standing still i get hundreds of meter of distance although it is inacurate but it should give almost 0 at the current location. see my code above

Comment: did you actually look at the 2 coords you get from your 2 "standing still" calls? did you plug them into a map to see what you got?  did you calculate the distance between those calls some other way not using this call?  Like I've been saying, any 2 calls could give you 2 answers.  the first call might get you tower assisted coords, which are very innacurate.  the second call might get a proper gps fix, giving you a more precise answer, which is different than the first!

Answer (score 1):

At best, a GPS is only [accurate](http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/) to 3 meters.  The more likely error is 5 - 10 meters.

You're going to have to [augment](http://www.gps.gov/systems/augmentations/) your GPS readings to get better accuracy.

Comment: The GPS Standard Positioning Service (which is all you got unless you've got special military hardware), at best offers +/- 7.8 meters in 3 dimensions at a 95% confidence level. That's a sphere of uncertainty 52 feet in diameter. You can read the current edition of the standard at http://www.gps.gov/technical/ps/. That's the best case. There are many other sources of entropy that reduce the precision of the solution, including hardware/software issues on the part of the GPS receiver, atmospheric and other external factors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

so far accuracy is not an issue. i run this app and the reading at current location changes continuously while i have set movementthreshold to 1 means 1 meter of distance needs to be covered to call PositionChanged event but reading keeps on changing even though i am still

Answer (score 0):

The other posters here are generally correct: GPS will not give you the accuracy you need. At least not alone!

Assuming you did have a good satellite fix, you could get an accuracy of centimeters, but this would require post-processing with information from special fixed stations or a live feed of data from such a station. The buzzwords here are "real-time phase differential", "real-time kinematic", "phase-differential post-processing".

[This site](http://www.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/edu/rtk_e.php) has some details.

So, if you can get access to feed, it *may* be possible. But it will not be as easy as you probably hoped.