# calculating distance travelled through windows phone.

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am developing a distance tracker application in which I am calculating the distance travelled by phone from the point I started to the point I ended with. I have tried with samples of GPS and acceleromeer but still confused with the actual key for the problem . Please suggest me with few solutions if you understood what my requirement is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825963/gps-to-calculate-distance-between-two-points-on-windows-phone-7?rq=1

Comment: Cant it be done with an accelerometer..? GPS comes with internet connectivity and accuracy issues..!!

Comment: It should be possible, but I could not find a tutorial for you, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to track the location using GPS. I assume since you have GPS samples that you've done that.

Then, you need to calculate the distance between two points. Position is given in terms of latitude and longitude. See this for an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12269/Distance-between-locations-using-latitude-and-long